# How can you run a report from the ReportServer database without building subscriptions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'd like to build a back end system that allows me to run each report every night and then query the execution log to see if anything failed. I know you can build out subscriptions for these reports and define parameters etc but is there a way to execute each report from the ReportServer database using TSQL without building out each subscription?

Comment: What do you mean "run"? As in, send it as an email? Then yes, you want a subscription; why can't/do you not want to use them?

Comment: I just want the report to execute - I don't need an email or anything. I don't even want to see the results. I just want the report to log to the ExecutionLog. I don't want to build a subscription for each report because there are over 300 of them.

Comment: But if it executes, and does nothing, then what's the point? Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). It would be like having a task in Agent to run a `SELECT` statement, but then nothing else... it would simply be a waste of resources.

Comment: If it executes and fails - it will log a failure in ExecutionLog. It it executes and succeeds it will log success in ExecutionLog. It's not an XY problem. I clearly stated that I want to test to make sure each report is running successfully on a scheduled basis. To do this I just need to execute the reports and make sure that there aren't subreports missing, data errors, missing data sources or any sort of broken link.

Comment: If the answer is "No, it can't be done" that's okay too

Comment: Then the answer is "no". You would either need to create a subscription, or have some kind of automated tool visit the specific URL of the deployed report (with the correct parameters). A SSRS report won't just "run" on it's own; as that would be a waste of resources. It sounds like, however, what you should really be doing is having automated tasks to check for things that will cause your reports to fail; for example if you know that a divide by zero error could occur, implement logic to stop/report that. So there's your X; and running your reports without "running" it is the Y. :)

Comment: Thank you - I kind of figured that would be the case. I wasn't sure if there was a way to execute a report with just TSQL behind the scenes, kind of like a subscription but without any artifact.

Comment: Have you tried using a snapshot?  That will execute the query/dataset aspect of the report, though it wouldn't capture render errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your overall goal is that you want to automate this and not have to write a subscription for every report.  You say you want to do it in T-SQL, but is that required to meet your overall goal?

If you can accept, say .Net, then you can use the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection and related classes to query your report server catalog and fetch a listing of all your reports.

Then you can use System.Net.WebClient or similar tool to attempt to download a pdf of your report.  From there you can either read your execution log, or catch the error in the .Net Code.

**EDIT**

Well, since you accepted the answer, and it seems you may go this route, I'll mention that if you're not familiar with .net, it may be a long path for you.  Here's a few things to get you started.

Below is a c# function utilizing .Net that will query the report catalog.  If safeImmediate is set to true, it will only capture reports that can be run immediately, as in there are no parameters or the defaults cover the parameters.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetReportPaths(
    string conStr,
    bool safeImmediate // as in, you can exexute the report right away without paramters
) {

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = @"select path from catalog where type=2";
        con.Open();

        if (safeImmediate) 
            cmd.CommandText = @"

                select      path
                from        catalog 
                cross apply (select 
                                params = convert(xml, Parameter).value('count(Parameters/Parameter)', 'int'),
                                defaults = convert(xml, Parameter).value('count(Parameters/Parameter/DefaultValues/Value)', 'int')
                            ) counts
                where       type = 2  
                and         params = defaults
                and         path not like '%subreport%' -- this is not standard.  Just works for my conventions

            ";

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        while (rdr.Read()) 
            yield return rdr["path"].ToString();

    }

}
```

The next function will download a report given proper paths passed to it:

```
byte[] DownloadReport (
    WebClient wc, 
    string coreUrl, 
    string fullReportPath, 
    string parameters = "" // you won't use this but may come in handy for other uses
) {
    var pathToViewer = "ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx"; // for typical ssrs installs
    var renderOptions = "&rs:Format=pdf&rs:Command=Render"; // return as pdf
    var url = $@"{coreUrl}/{pathToViewer}?{fullReportPath}{parameters}{renderOptions}";
    url = Uri.EscapeUriString(url); // url's don't like certain characters, fix it
    return wc.DownloadData(url); 
}
```

And this utilizes the functions above to find what's succeeding and whats not:

```
    var sqlCon = "Server=yourReportServer; Database=ReportServer; Integrated Security=yes"; // or whatever
    var ssrsSite = "http://www.yourSite.org";

    using (var wc = new WebClient()) {

        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true; // or whatever

        int loops = 3; // get rid of this when you're ready for prime-time

        foreach(var path in GetReportPaths(sqlCon, true)) {

            try {
                DownloadReport(wc, ssrsSite, path);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Success with: {path}");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { // you might want to get more specific
                Debug.WriteLine($"Failed with: {path}"); 
            }

            if (loops-- == 0)
                break;

        }

    }
```

Lots to learn, but it can be very beneficial.  Good luck.

Comment: I looked into it earlier - I'm not too familiar with .Net but I considered it. I was aiming for SQL but this might work. Thank you